# How to force clang use llvm assembler instead of system?

Tags: c++, assembly, clang, llvm

I'm working on LLVM/Clang [fork](https://github.com/4ntoine/clang) (for AVR). How can i force Clang Driver to use LLVM assembler instead of system one?

> MBA-Anton:bin asmirnov$ ./clang++
>   -I/Applications/avr.app/Contents/Resources/Java/hardware/avr/cores/avr -I/Applications/avr.app/Contents/Resources/Java/hardware/avr/variants/standard
>   /var/folders/64/fwfkm1k51zbd4_c5lwpsbljh0000gn/T/build5450310618632673119.tmp/Blink.cpp
>   -o /tmp/Blink.avr.hex -I /Applications/avr.app//Contents/Resources/Java/hardware/tools/avr/avr/include/
>   --target=avr -O1 -v

And it uses LLVM clang compiler (not system, correct):

```
clang version 3.6.0 (https://github.com/4ntoine/clang.git 0d08deedd548d964f63cf896ae9acb8d878a5fd8)     (https://github.com/dylanmckay/avr-llvm.git 447b58bced825fa7bea31f3882f277535cc9fca6)
Target: avr
Thread model: posix
"/Users/asmirnov/Documents/dev/src/llvm_dylan/installed/bin/clang" -cc1 ...
```

But system assembler (incorrect):

> "/usr/bin/as" -o ...

It should use LLVM's `llvm-as` as it "knows" AVR target (opcodes, etc). How can i force it use LLVM's assembler?

Comment: Can you try passing the `-integrated-as` option and check again? If it works, I will post it as an answer.

Comment: with `-integrated-as` it starts using `g++` and system linker (`ld`) after clang compiler for some reason: `"/usr/bin/g++" ...
 "/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/ld" ...` and it's completely incorrect

Comment: after further investigation i've found using integrated assembler was correct answer. The only difference i had to override toolchain method to use integrated assembler by default

Answer (score 0):

You can use clang to emit LLVM IR code by using the option `-emit-llvm`.

Let's say you want to compile a C file into LLVM IR:

`clang -emit-llvm -c file.c`

It will create a LLVM bytecode file `file.bc`. You will be able to compile the file with [llc](http://linux.die.net/man/1/llc).

Comment: You're right but i need not only produce IR, but compile machine-code for the target CPU